# set Focus on a view inside Listener

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm building a Plugin with the [JCEF Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef) for a Eclispe rcp. the Framework is written in C++ and has wrapper for Java. With the framework I get a browser in a Component

I have a curios Problem, which needs some steps to get there:

1. Click (set focus) to a random view in the rcp
2. Click in the browser
3. open another window (e.g. windows explorer)
4. click on the close button from the rcp

then a dialog box opens and ask if you want to close the program. The problem is that you cant click on yes or no, only if you click on another view again. The problem only occurs with my plugin.

I have added the Component to a Frame in the createPartControl methode:

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
    //create the browser
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
    frame.add(browser_component);
    //do some other stuff 
}
```

Do someone know what the problem could be?

If not, I thought about a workaround, that I will set the focus on my view from my code, if I click on the browser. I can create and add a FocusListener for the Browser. 
My attempt:

```
    //in the methode of the FocusListener  
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("myview");
```

But it throws an Invalid thread access Exception